# How to remove border of a cell with html and css?

Tags: html, css, border

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
    padding: 5px;
}
.border-none{
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pc</td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-none"></th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>100</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I've the table looks like this:

[image]

But how could I remove the first cell in the last row:

[image]

Also I've tried:

```
style='border:none;'
```

and

```
style='border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-top:none'
```

But without any change, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can simply set directly your td and th: `th, td{ border: 1px solid grey; } tfoot th:first-child { border:0; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could target the 'last of type' `tr` and 'first of type' `td` in the table footer.

You can see that I had to remove the border from the `table` element also, as this surrounded the whole table

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}
th,td{
    padding: 5px;
}
.border-none{
    border:none;
}

tfoot tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pc</td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-none"></th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>100</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust you css to:

```
.border-none{
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
    padding: 5px;
}
.border-none{
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pc</td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-none"></th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>100</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td{
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
}
.border-none{
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Qte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pc</td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-none"></th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>100</th>
      <th>5</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: it does not look like he expects